# Running external program in matlab and getting output results

Tags: matlab, system, external

I need to write a script that will run external program from matlab and to get output results from it. This program should simulate 20 variants. I made those 20 files in matlab, and I'm able to open external program, but I am not able to write a command that will simulate the files in it. And return me output results. (Input files have .idf extension and output .eso)

I tried with these and similar commands

```
for id=1:20;
    system(sprintf('C:\...\myprogram.exe<''variant_%i.idf',id));
    i=1+1;
end
```

or

```
for id=1:20;
     cmd_line = '"C:\...\myprogram.exe" -f variant_%i.idf -o variant_%i.eso';
     [status, result] = system(cmd_line);
     i=1+1;
 end
```

I need to do this for exam, and I had only 3 weeks of matlab and never studied programming, so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I don't know where else to ask.

Comment: "that will simulate the files in it" what does that mean? Did you succeed to run the Tool via command promt (cmd.exe)? Which command line did you use?

Comment: two questions:1)what error message are you getting? 2)have your tried to call this exe directly from command line? did it work? how did you call it? two of the things that are obviously wrong: 1) in your loop you are iterating through variable id, but you are using i as the input to the program (line 2 of both snippet.) 2) I think you need to change your "\" to "/" when using sprintf.

Comment: @Cici - 1) With first try I get this error message > In windowsize at 32 
Warning: Escape sequence 'E' is not valid. See 'help sprintf' for valid escape sequences. With second command the program opens but doesn't do anything. 2)I tried to call exe directly from the command line and it opens. I used: system('C:\..\myprogram.exe')

Comment: @Cici 1) I'm using i because it was done like that in some example in the class and it is working, and if I change it to id nothing changes. I guessed this i stands for i used in name of variant files (variant_%i), because I get 20 files variant_1, variant_2...
I tried using \\ instead of \ (professor told us that we should use it because of this external program) and I get error message: The system cannot find the file specified. 
If I use / I get the same message.
Thank you for your help

Comment: @Daniel - It means that this program needs to simulate 20 variants and to return outputs. Those are variants of a template file that I read, changed and saved using matlab script. I can run the tool from cmd.exe using it's path.
Thank you

Comment: The error message is because the "\". "\" specify an escape sequence. that's why "/" is better. On thing you can do is to test the sprintf function separately and see if it give you a valid command (one that produce a command line that you can run in cmd.exe). I was reading the "%i" thing wrong, sorry about that.

Comment: @Cici I tried to use sprintf in command window like this: sprintf('C:\\...\\mzprogram.exe<''variant_%i.idf')
and I get ans= C:\...\myprogram.exe<'model_

Is it possible that "%" sign is a problem here?

Comment: try: id=1; sprintf(['C:/.../myprogram.exe<' 'variant_%i.idf'],id); this should give you: C:/.../myprogram.exe<variant_1.idf; will this run in your command window? and I assume rather than "..." you are using a real path on your computer?

Comment: @Cici I tried this and I get that with an apostrophe after <   (C:/.../myprogram.exe<'variant_1.idf)   
 Yes, I used real path :)

Comment: did you put in space between the two ' ?  sprintf(['C:/.../myprogram.exe<'[there is a space here]'variant_%i.idf'],id);

Comment: @Cici Sorry, I didn't notice the space there. Now I tried it and I get that answer. Then I tried to put this into script:  
    for id=1:20;
     name = sprintf(['C:/.../myprogram.exe.exe<'   'variant_%i.idf'],id);
     result = system(name);
    i=1+1;
    end
---- The program is now running, but it is still not opening specified files.

Comment: does not open or does not output specified files. if you just run C:/.../myprogram.exe<variant_1.idf; in your command window does it work?

Comment: The program opens, but it doesn't do anything. It doesn't open any file. If I run this in command window, I get: Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.

Answer (score 1):

You may change your "myprogram.exe" in order to report the output data into a file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how do you mean to change "myprogram.exe". Could you please clarify? Thank you

Comment: I mean you can change your "myprogram.exe" to run in different modes based on an extra input. That extra input could be your variable "id" (your loop variable). Based on "id" you can generate different outputs or report your results onto different output files.