# How to call PHP from MATLAB?

Tags: php, matlab, server, data-transfer

I have some analysed data in MATLAB which I need to send to a server. I have a php link to access the server. Any idea how to call php from MATLAB?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running external program in matlab and getting output results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046758/running-external-program-in-matlab-and-getting-output-results)

Comment: @rpax really? I don't see how to call php in that question.

Comment: So, do you want to call php or to send an HTTP request?. There are two different things.

Comment: @rpax I want to send data by calling the php with some parameters I have . PHP needs to be called inside MATLAB function. Is it possible?

Comment: calling the _php executable_ or making a GET/POST request?

Comment: My URL should be like this. When I call this the data is stored in the database in the server. 

[link]https://smrt.utd.edu.sg/Analysis/Results.php?gender=Female&age=50&purpose=H

Answer (score 0):

If you will frequently send data back and forth between MATLAB and your web server, perhaps you can consider using SaturnAPI. [SaturnAPI](http://saturnapi.com/) provides a REST interface for your Matlab and Octave scripts, so that you don't have to install anything on your own server. It can even send Base64 encoded 3D plots to you. Here is the [demo](https://saturnapi.com/demo). Below is a diagram showing that you can pass inputs to the script via the `SaturnParams` variable in the HTTP call.

[image]

Disclosure: I work on SaturnAPI

Comment: Thanks. In my case I have to call this php because I have no other way of accessing the server. The php will write my data into the database. 

Anyway this SaturnAPI looks cool. Thanks for letting me know that it exists.

Comment: @Hasala - how much data do you need to send at a time, i.e. KBs, MBs, GB? That could also dictate your options

Comment: My data are in kBs but send real time data. So the number of requests are very high.

Comment: @Hasala - okay, and how are the MATLAB computations initiated?

Comment: I compute and get some final results as parameters that I need to send to the server by calling the PHP.